# Spring Oauth2 authorization server allow instropect without authentication

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

In Spring Oauth2 Authorization server there is a build in endpoint `/oauth2/introspect` to check the token but it will required to authenticate before showing the response.But the requirement is to check the token without authentication.As code show below i tried to permit all the build in endpoint `/oauth2/introspect**` to permit all but it still trying to authenticate.

maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Code

```
  @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors()
                .configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration()
                        .applyPermitDefaultValues());

        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity> authorizationServerConfigurer =
                new OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer<>();
        RequestMatcher endpointsMatcher = authorizationServerConfigurer.getEndpointsMatcher();


        http.csrf().disable();
        http.requestMatcher(endpointsMatcher)
                .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                        authorizeRequests
                                .antMatchers("/oauth2/introspect**").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringAntMatchers("/oauth2/token**","/oauth2/introspect**"))
                .apply(authorizationServerConfigurer);
        

        return http.build();
    }


    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient
                .withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("client")
                .clientSecret("{noop}secret")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder()
                        .tokenEndpointAuthenticationSigningAlgorithm(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256)
                        .build())
                .tokenSettings(TokenSettings.builder()
                        .accessTokenFormat(OAuth2TokenFormat.REFERENCE)
                        .idTokenSignatureAlgorithm(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256)
                        .accessTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofMinutes(15))
                        .build())
                .scope("read")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
    }
```